# Spring incoming request mapping

Tags: json, spring-mvc, mapping

**Model classes:**

```
public class UserModel {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public EducationModel education;

    public UserModel(int id, String name, EducationModel education) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.education = education;
    }
    public UserModel() {}
}

public class EducationModel {
    public String degree;
    public String institution;

    public EducationModel(String degree, String institution) {
        this.degree = degree;
        this.institution = institution;
    }
    public EducationModel() {}
}
```

**UserModel** uses **EducationModel**.

I want to do is that if I pass *json of UserModel* with an additional *EducationModel* object in it, to parse and map the json to these models.

The problem is that Spring for some reason does not like the constructor in EducationModel and returns null every time. If I remove the constructor it works. But I need the constructor for other methods. As you can see the UserModel also uses custom constructor but it maps everything correctly. When it comes to EducationModel it just returns null all the time.

So, is there a way to fix this without losing the constructor?

Comment: What's spring config that you are using?

Comment: Where do I find one? I didnt do any configuration on my own so there might just be default

Comment: How are you using those two above classes in code then?

Comment: Since it is rest, there is a controller that expects to get post request with RequestBody UserModel userModel. This is not the same code I just made an example accordingly